# Does Newark Terminal B have Automated Passport Control?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, ewr

Does Newark(EWR) Terminal B now have [Automated Passport Control terminals](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/automated-passport-control-apc#) (APC)? I can find reference to them being in Terminal C but no reference to B.

Comment: APC terminals??

Comment: @Karlson I think it's the name for the electronic machines for US citizens + ESTA holders to do much of the immigration interview/question stuff

Comment: sorry - Automated Passport Control -  http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/automated-passport-control-apc#

Comment: I crossposted this excellent question to http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/25543342-post115.html

Answer (score 4):

OK - having done the trip i can confirm as at October 2015 no APC units in terminal B. This does mean joining the traditional long queue at immigration.

Comment: I flew into Newark two days ago and no APC units.  I guess that was terminal B.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to prove a negative as there doesn't seem to have an official page for this but according to http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/25545204-post117.html

> I know there are GE (cuz that's all I use there ), but never saw signs for APC (which I HAVE seen signs for in Terminal C)