# Status of APC (automated passport control) kiosks in US airports?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

Is there somewhere a list of all US airports with automated passport control kiosks?

I have used them at NY (JFK), Boston, Chicago (ORD), Dallas (DFW).
I don't believe they are in place in Newark but might not recall right.

What about LAX for instance? SFO? MIA?
Easiest would be to have an up to date list somewhere - can this be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a list on the CBP website](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/apc). It's a fairly comprehensive list of international airports, including EWR, LAX, SFO, and MIA. However, some airports may have multiple immigration areas, and it's not necessarily the case that every passenger arriving at a listed airport is offered the use of a kiosk.

For example, there were [no APC kiosks at EWR's terminal B](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57228/does-newark-terminal-b-have-automated-passport-control) (there are Global Entry kiosks), though it looks like [the government was seeking a contractor to install some](http://www.newyorkbids.net/bid_opportunities/2017/06/12/7844702-verification-and-validation-process-vvp---newark-international-airport-ewr---terminal-b-automated.html). There are kiosks at Newark's terminal C. This level of detail can sometimes be found on airport websites, frequent flyer forums, or by googling.

Mobile Passport Control is also available at [a smaller list of airports](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/mobile-passport-control) for US and Canadian citizens.

And here's [the list of airports with Global Entry kiosks](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/locations), for members of that program.